# Book about how Kids dreams change due to TV, where the MC travels back to his dreamland to save it

Tags: story-identification

in my teens I've read a book in which a boy travels into his dream world and tries to rescue it. I'm trying to find it, sadly its not in my parents bookshelf anymore. The book was written in German, I do not know if it has been translated into English.

Here are some fragments I still remember:

- Before the kid reenters his dreamworld, characters from his dreamworld leak into the real world, where they are dying a slow death while comatose.
- Before the kid reenters his dreamworld, he sees his parents watch some horror flick about killer-robots which will later be the main enemy in the dreamworld
- The kid tries to enter his dreamworld by "using" his old lego-spaceship with which he entered the world when he was little, but fails and instead rides on the back of his sisters pet-lizard into the dream world.
- He encounters some creature which is ugly in the night and beautiful in the day calling it "Bröckchen, - kurz für Kotzbrocken" (german)
- At some point he finds the old Elven Tree in which the elves house. And realizes that unlike last time when the Tree grew the houses and furniture naturally, now they are cut out from the Tree / manufactured by the killer-robots
- After the adventure (when the kid wakes up) new Neighbors move in, and their Kids had important roles in the dream. The ugly/beautiful creature strongly resembles their (always ugly) family dog.